# Meteor does'nt rerender when user is adding to collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, reactive

When a new user is adding to the users collection the html does'nt re-render although I can see it in the websocket.

[websocket message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21v4R.png)

publication.js:

```
Meteor.publish('users.name.by-game', function(code) {
  check(code, String);
  this.autorun(function() {
    const game = Game.findOne({ code });
    return Meteor.users.find(
      { _id: { $in: (game && game.getPlayersId()) || [] } },
      { fields: { 'services.gitlab.username': 1 } },
    );
  });
});
```

subscribe line:

```
export default createContainer(({ code }) => {
  const imagesHandle = Meteor.subscribe('images.all');
  const usersHandle = Meteor.subscribe('users.name.by-game', code);
  const gameHandle = Meteor.subscribe('games.get-by-code', code);
  const loading = !imagesHandle.ready() || !gameHandle.ready() || 
                  !usersHandle.ready();
  const game = Game.findOne();
  return { loading, game };
}, GameRouterContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `this.autorun(function() {` inside the publish function.

Also, if the problem is about rendering, the code you pasted won't let us help you.

Comment: the autorun in the publication is needed to observe the changes in `game` so we can republish users in accordance. we know it works because without it we don't get the message about the new user added to the client. our problem is that after the message does get to the client it doesnt rerender...

Comment: I do not see your publish function returning any value.

Comment: The publications work - the client recieve the relevant data. The problem is that the UI does not render when a new user is adding to the game. Our publish function does return a value, you can see the package we use here - https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/reactive-publish

Comment: We changed the package to "reywood:publish-composite" and its dixed the problem. Thank you anyway :)